# Javafx focus listener is not working properly with mouse pressed event

Tags: javafx

Im getting wrong print values when i try to add a focus listener to a node

```
Vbox vb = new Vbox();

for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
Hbox hbox = new hbox(new Label("Number"+i));
vb.getChildren().add(hb);

hbox.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                   hbox.requestFocus();

            }

        });
  hbox.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal)
                -> System.out.println(newVal ? vb.getChildren().indexOf(hbox) + "Focused" : vb.getChildren().indexOf(hbox) + " Unfocused"));

}
```

what i want is to print when an hbox clicked get the focus node and unfocused node(previously focused node) using mouse pressed event. this works with mouse click event and mouse released event. but getting previously focused index taking some time.

Comment: ma bad. its the hbox node. i edited

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `focus` and `released`, the focus is when you press on a Node and it did not get unfocused until you focus on new Node. to get Mouse released event you need:

> onMouseReleasedProperty

the time it "take" it until you press on new Node and pass the focus on it(or close the program or press on other things...)

I use TextField for better understanding:

```
  VBox vb = new VBox();
        for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
            TextField hb = new TextField("Number"+i);
            vb.getChildren().add(hb);
            hb.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                    hb.requestFocus();
                }

            });

            hb.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    System.out.println(newValue ? vb.getChildren().indexOf(hb) + "Focused" : vb.getChildren().indexOf(hb) + " Unfocused");
                }
            });
        }
```

now you can see:

[image]

4 is with the focus and the focus  will stay until you press on other things(the focus didn't go on released)

Comment: okay great! well im kinda new. can you tell me how i should use it?

Comment: If you had a text field, for example, you can requestFocus to give the user the possibility to start type immediately(the style also change when focus in   text field), or in a big screen to scroll to this Node area on screen etc

Comment: what do you mean? i dont think that can help with my situation

Comment: that what Focus is for, it will not for MouseReleased, what are you try to achieve?

Comment: All the hbox are colored white. I wanna add the blue  color to hbox node on click. then i click another hbox previously colored hbox should go back to white color. i was gonna use focus events with mouse click since hbox don't offer focus on click.

Comment: and what should happen to the previous hbox?

Comment: previous one go back to white color. clicked/focused one be blue color im trying to make a custom list component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187517/discussion-between-sarel-foyerlicht-and-uthpala-bandara).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can see the focus property changing.  When an hbox is clicked using css it will set the border and when its not it focus it will remove the border

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        VBox vb = new VBox();

        for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
            HBox hBox = new HBox(new Label("Number"+i));
            hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            vb.getChildren().add(hBox);

            hBox.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> hBox.requestFocus());

            hBox.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                System.out.println(newVal ? vb.getChildren().indexOf(hBox) + " Focused" : vb.getChildren().indexOf(hBox) + " Unfocused");
                if(newVal)
                    hBox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: blue;");
                else
                    hBox.setStyle(null);
            });

        }

        Stage stage  = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vb));
        stage.setWidth(100);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: issue is when i put vbox in to a scrollpane it's not working. any idea why?

Comment: you need to consume the event

hb.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
hb.requestFocus(); 
e.consume(); 
} 
});